# I can't install 'aptitude'

Tags: apt, dependencies, aptitude

I was trying to install `aptitude`, but it showed me this message:

> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: What happened when you run the suggested command?

Comment: Before you do anything else run `sudo apt-get -f install`